# Migration from Microsoft.Net C# 2010/2008(3.5) Framework to 2012 (4.5) Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

i was planning to Migrate my application in 2008(3.5 Frame work) and 2010 (4.0) Frame Work to 2012 (4.5 Frame work). Any one over here have any inputs regarding this.

Comment: 4.5 is only available on Vista and later. Otherwise you basically change the target framework in Project Properties and off you go.

Comment: when you open your app in visual studio 2012 it will change your app to 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to ask SO. This is a common scenario and is well-documented on MSDN:

- [Migration Guide to the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657133%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Migration Guide to the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [.NET Framework 4 Migration Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee941656%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)